# A proof of a certain identity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Here is the question and the answer of part(a)

> [image]
>   [image]

But I do not know how to answer part(b), any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you can try to start from the convexity inequality:
$$f(s) \leq \frac{t-s}{t-r}f(r) + \frac{s-r}{t-r}f(t)$$
and then try to find a lower-bound on $\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}$, meaning find a quantity on the right-hand side in:
$$\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} \geq \; ...$$
Then you should try to use (a) to conclude.

Comment: I have a problem in a negative sign , could you provide the details for me please?

Comment: Can you please write your computations so that we can see where there is a problem?

Comment: I have tackled the right solution thank you :)